# How to declare vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to use a vector of strings in my code instead of an array of strings but apparently I miss some detail in the declaration of the vector. Using the following code, I get this error: `‘vector’ was not declared in this scope`

```
// Try to implement a vector of string elements

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
    vector<string> my_vector(MAX_ITEMS);
    return 0;
}
```

How should I correctly declare the vector?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add these includes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

Comment: So, all the while, I was using a strange version of strings? What are the differences between the std one and the one included in <string>?

Comment: @Morlock: This is the standard string. Perhaps your `<iostream>` includes `<string>` for you (some implementations do, others don't) but there's no reason for it to include `<vector>`.

Comment: @UncleBens Thanks for the the details. I thought I came across something stating that there was a string type normally implemented, but that it was better to prefer the one from <string>. I think I saw this in the cplusplus.com C++ tutorial.

Answer (score 9):

You have to include the header:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
#include <vector>
```